Check failed: ret == 0 (11 vs. 0)Thread tf_Compute creation via pthread_create() failed
When I run keras.load_model and make_predict_function on a Django application that has been deployed on cPanel.
An error occurs: Check failed:
ret == 0 (11 vs. 0)Thread tf_Compute creation via pthread_create() failed.

import os
os.environ['TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS'] = '2' # {0,1,2,3,4}
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
 
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.keras.preprocessing import image as kerasImage

model_dir = settings.BASE_DIR / "/static/model.h5"
model = load_model(model_dir)
model.make_predict_function()

# actual class labels
class_labels = ["kencur", “temulawak”, “ginger”, “turmeric”, “galangal”]

# Proccesing image by keras
i = kerasImage.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
i = kerasImage.i(i) / 255.0
shape = i.reshape(1, 224, 224, 3)
p = model.predict(shape)

When running a Django app to load_model using a trained model stored in the root static directory.
I use Python version 7.3 and Tensorflow / hardware version 2.11.0 on my cPanel.
How do I resolve this?
